# why byte ordering (endianess) is not an issue for standard C string?

Tags: c, string, endianness

My professor mentioned that `byte ordering (endianess)` is not an issue for `standard C String` (`Char arrays`):

for ex: `char[6]="abcde";`

But he did not explain why?

Any explanations for this will be helpful

Comment: In what situations do you anticipate that there might be an issue?

Comment: I dont know what he meant by that. Thats why I ask for explanation

Comment: It only makes a difference when individual elements are larger than 1 byte. Since a string is an array of single-byte elements, there's nothing to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `char` takes up only one byte, thats why the ordering does not matter. for example, `int` has 4 bytes and these bytes could be arranged in little-endian and big-endian`.

Eg: `0x00010204` can be arranged in two ways in memory:

```
04 02 01 00 or 00 01 02 04
```

`char` being a single byte will be fetched as single byte to `CPU`. and `String` is just a `char`array.

Comment: is it the same case in `Java`?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: As I recall, Java strings use 16-bit characters, so byte order could be an issue -- but only if you access a Java string as if it were a byte array, which you ordinarily wouldn't do.

Comment: yes, Java `char` uses `2-bytes` as opposed to `1 bytes` in `C`. I don't know if Java stores `String` as `char array` internally.

Comment: @user1988876 The big-endian representation should've been `00 01 02 04` rather than `00 01 02 03 04`.

Answer (score 2):

Endianess only matters when you have multi-byte data (like integers and floating point numbers).  Standard C strings consist of 1-byte characters, so you don't need to worry about endianness.

Comment: [Bit endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian#.22Bit_endianness.22), within 1 byte, does come into play in select coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Smallest Unit of memory storage is 1 Byte, If you have a 4 byte value ( ex : 0x01234567 )
It will be arranged and fetched in the order of Endianness in contigous locations

Big Endian : 01 23 45 67 
Little Endian : 67 45 23 01

Whereas for a 1 byte Value it can be fetched from one memory location itself since that is the smallest block of memory , with no need for byte ordering .

Hope this Helps !